# Calculate percentage for list of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, math, percentage, calculus

I have a list of integer values (positive, and negative). I need to calculate the percentage of each value. Is there any API in Java to achieve this?

Example 1 -

`10, 40, 60, -15, -25, 30, -10, -50, 120`

`-50 (lowest value) - 0%
 -25 - ?
 -15 - ?
 -10 - ?
 10 - ?
 120 (highest value) - 100%`

Example 2 -

90, 45, 13, -89, -95, -150, 200, 250, 67

-150 (lowest value) - 0%
-95 - ?
-89 - ?
13 - ?
250  (highest value) - 100%

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  Provide several examples of input, and the expected output in each case.

Comment: Percentage reflects a ratio 95% = 95/100 and is usually limited [0, 100]. Negative percent and values >100 usually don't make sense, unless you provide a base or it reflects a relative change: 120% of the original value, -25% change, etc. Could you clarify the basis for the calculation? What are you trying to achieve with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are asking for normalizing based on the index after sorting or the value. But I think based on value makes more sense. For example if your array is `0, 1, 10`, the final percentages will be `0->0%, 1->10%, 10->100%`

For this, you will basically do a normalization.

I don't remember the exact syntax but correct it if any syntax is wrong.

```
int arr[] = {10, 40, 60, -15, -25, 30, -10, -50};

List b = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(arr));

int mn = Collections.min(b);
int mx = Collections.max(b);

int perc_arr = new int[arr.length];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
     perc_arr[i] = (arr[i]-mn)/(mx-mn)*100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an API for this, just store the numbers in an Array, sort it, and get the percentage as follows :

```
int []array = new int[n];
//insert numbers in the list
Arrays.sort();
```

Suppose you need to find the percentage of a given number `'x'`, then do this :

```
int index = ArrayUtils.indexOf(array, x);
int percentage = ((double)(index + 1)/n)*100
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an API / external class.  You can make a method.  Here is some basic pseudocode-esk java to get you started

```
public int average (arraylist a or int[] a){
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< a.length or a.size(); i++){
        r+= a[i] or r+= a.get(i);
    }
    r = (r/a.length) or (r/a.size());
    return r;
}
```